# I was wondering how i can achieve the blue-ish box behind the image

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

i was wondering if you can help me achieve this look. I have my MUI app bar and my home page. I was wondering how i can achieve the blue-ish box behind the image. Should I place the container inside my app bar or place it inside my homepage file? If you see the image of my output, there's a huge gab between the app bar and the title. I would like to avoid that also.

what i want to achieve:
[image: what i want to achieve]

what i get:
[image]

here is the part of the code code:

```
return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Grid container component="main" sx={{ backgroundColor: '#FBF3EA', display: "flex", justifyContent: "center", position: 'absolute' }} >
            <Box component="section">
                <Container sx={{ py: 10 }} maxWidth="lg">
                    <Grid container alignItems="center" spacing={3}>
                        <Grid item xs={12} md={5}>
                            <Box sx={{
                                display: 'flex',
                                ml: '850px',
                                width: '500px',
                                mt: '-160px'
                            }}>
                                <Container sx={{backgroundColor: '#99CCCB', width: 300, height: 500 }} xs={12} sm={6} md={6}></Container >
                            </Box>
                            <Typography component="h1" variant="h3">
                                Real Pet food fresh from the fridge.
                            </Typography>
                            <Stack direction="row" spacing={2} sx={{ mt: 4 }}>
                                <Button size="large" variant="contained" sx={{
                                    backgroundColor: '#124944',
                                    textTransform: 'none'
                                }}>
                                    Shop Now
                                </Button>
                            </Stack>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item>
                            <Grid container sx={{display: 'flex', flexWrap: 'nowrap'}}>
                                <Grid item>
                                    <img width="150px" height="175px" src={dogHome} alt="dog food" />
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid item sx={{width:'100%'}}>
                                    <Card>
                                        <CardContent>
                                            <Grid container spacing={3}
                                                  sx={{
                                                      "& .MuiGrid-item:last-child > .MuiBox-root": {
                                                          border: "none",
                                                      },
                                                  }}>
                                                <Grid item>
                                                    <Box >
                                                        <Typography fontFamily="Righteous" gutterBottom color="text.secondary" variant="h4" sx={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center'}}> 200 + </Typography>
                                                        <Typography fontFamily="Righteous" variant="h5" sx={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center'}}> Nutritional Complete </Typography>
                                                    </Box>
                                                </Grid>
                                                <Grid item>
                                                    <Box>
                                                        <Typography fontFamily="Righteous" gutterBottom color="text.secondary" variant="h4" sx={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center'}}> 1k </Typography>
                                                        <Typography fontFamily="Righteous" variant="h5" sx={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center'}}> Product Sales </Typography>
                                               </Box>
                                                </Grid>
                                                <Grid item>
                                                    <Box>
                                                        <Typography fontFamily="Righteous" gutterBottom color="text.secondary" variant="h4" sx={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center'}}> 96% </Typography>
                                                            <Typography fontFamily="Righteous" variant="h5" sx={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center'}}> Client Satisfaction </Typography>
                                                    </Box>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </CardContent>
                                    </Card>
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
```

Comment: I would try it with `box-shadow`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `position: absolute` and `z-index: -1` on your `Box` element:

```
<Box sx={{
    display: 'flex',
    position: 'absolute',
    top: '0px',
    right: '200px', // adjust this
    width: '500px',
    zIndex: '-1'
}}>
```

Comment: position absolute makes the box disappear

Comment: @ElenaSoteriou Did you also apply the `top` and `right` values?

Comment: yes i did apply top and right values